# Entity Framework: EF4 – update model from database doens't work

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

i'm using VS 2010 with EF 4.0 and i have a problem that i've searched in conteless foruns and websites but can't found an answer to my question.

I have a DB that i'm using for my final project in C# with EF. What appens is when i'm tring to upgrade my data model (because i made changes in my DB, i.e, added more features likes tables), the tables that i've created appears in the "Add" tab but not on the final model. I tried to delete the model and recreat it but the problem remains.

I read a lot of responses for this issue but non of them solved my problem. I'm stucked and i can't move on with my project without resolving this.

Thank you in advance,
Ricardo Gomes
Portugal

Comment: I found myself doing this before, did you make sure to check the box next to the tables you're looking to add?

Comment: yes, of course. i tried to update the model and it only apeares the 3 tables i want to add. with this done in model they continue not to apeear. even deleting the model and creating a new one doesn't work. this 3 tables apears in the in add tab with all the others but not in the final model

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before when trying to add a table which had all nullable fields and no key.